# What is the right way to initialize a php associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am going to construct a highly complex associative array in php. But first, I need to initialize it.

What is the right way to initialize it? My initialization is as follows;

```
$ComplexAssociativeArray = [];
```

Are there better ways?

Comment: Why negative point? The reason I asked was that I saw different ways of initializing while googling. Not sure which is the best way.

Answer (score 3):

If you go for

```
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
```

It wont work in php versions before 5.4

but below way work in all versions

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

I think that is the main difference.

Quoting from [**php docs for arrays**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].